# Good OO naming scheme for c

Tags: c, oop, coding-style, naming-conventions, naming

I find myself with a lot of functions that are oo style in c(nothing with fancy macros or function pointers just struct + functions that take that struct type as a first argument.
Is my_func_my_type a good scheme for such things? If I use that should I try to be consistent? what if it one of my functions name becomes > 20 characters? > 25? Should I keep the style consistent even then?

Also what is a good naming scheme for constructors/initializers/destructors?
Is there something beter then new_my_type , init_my_type, free_my_type ?

P.S. Is there a good name for this/self ptr or should I just name the first parameter of OO like function as I would in a normal function (to_init, some_guy,ect.)

Answer (score 3):

I would personally use a scheme consistent with most C libraries that put the library name as a prefix of the function. Which would give for instance `void MyObject_MyFunction`. For construction/destruction, you can stay consistent and use `MyObject_Construct`, `MyObject_Destroy`. I'd say the name don't matter much as long as you stay consistent.

Answer (score 1):

'good' is a bit subjective, but I find it the easiest to maintain to choose a certain scheme (incorporating struct name into method) and follow it strictly. Really long function names I tend to avoid though, if a function is so complicated that it need such a long name it's probably time to refactor it, split into subfunctions etc.
I also do not use underscores, but that's a matter of taste.
A sample of what's used here:

```
typedef struct Discriminator
{
  //members
} Discriminator;

DiscriminatorConstruct( Discriminator* p );
DiscriminatorDestruct( Discriminator* p );
DiscriminatorFunctionA( Discriminator* p, int arg1, int arg2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

For lack of one within the C world, C++ provides a useful precedent in the naming of its functions:

```
[[namespace::...]struct::]function
```

There's nothing like namespaces in C, but you can just think of and model them as prefixes shared by related structs.  For readability, it helps to have something to visually separate the distinct naming components.  If you like using underscores in your functions, you might consider two underscores as a separator, otherwise perhaps one.  (Technically, two underscores may be reserved for the implementation, but I've never seen any implementation identifier that wasn't prefixed with underscores put a double underscore internally).

Keeping the names close to C++ also helps programmers span both languages, and in migrating code back and forth if necessary.  Similarly, C++ terminology may be adopted: *constructor*, *destructor*, possibly *new* and *delete* (though these names may become misnomers if the C code is ported to C++ but continues to use free/malloc).

IMHO, consistent and clear naming saves more hassles than long identifiers cause, but if something becomes a pain then seek a localised workaround such as a macro, inline wrapper function, function pointer etc..

Comment: If you only recommend C++ this answer is incomplete. **Objective-C**??!

Comment: @Radek: feel free to comment or post your own reply with whatever precedents Objective-C sets - I've never used or looked at it....

Comment: oh than it's a whole other story, but Objective-C is pretty much used these days.